# How to reset npm files

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I was trying to install a library yesterday and I am quite new to this - long story short I messed all the files up.
Instead of fixing my problem which I am quite unsure of what it is. I think it would be a lot easier just to reset all the files for `npm`. How can I delete and reinstall all `npm` files so it would end up as I just downloaded everything.

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

Comment: are you talking project specific files or did it mess with your global packages?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sometimes npm's cache gets confused. You can reset it using:

```
 npm cache clean
```

If you want to set default value to npm configuration then try this:

```
echo "" > $(npm config get userconfig)
npm config edit
```

For resetting global configuration for windows.

```
echo "" > $(npm config get globalconfig)
npm config --global edit
```

For sudoers

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "" > $(npm config get globalconfig)'
```

Answer (score 0):

`rm -rf node_modules`  to delete all the modules and `npm install` to install them